# Replace matching text with href links

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string like:

```
@test hello how are you @abcdef
```

How would I automatically make it so it converts all text that has @ to something like:

```
https://example.com/test
https://example.com/abcdef
```

I've tried using regex and preg_replace but can't get it down perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex [`@(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/I4RFty/1) with substitution `https://example.com/$1`:

```php
$string = '@test hello how are you @abcdef';

$result = preg_replace('/@(\S+)/', 'https://example.com/$1', $string);

print($result);
```

Comment: If there was @abcdef<br> how would you recommend getting rid of the <br> inside of the regex?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the tag completely, try something like [`@(\w+)(?:<[^<>]*>)?`](https://regex101.com/r/Ao2CKk/1)